# Ruby - Receiving Form Data

Tags: ruby, cgi

I have a form like this:

```
<form>
  <textarea name="txtarea" cols="60" rows="20"></textarea><br/>
  <input type="submit" value="SUBMIT"/>
</form>
```

in my Ruby CGI script. How can I get the values of txtarea when the user clicks the submit button without using Ruby on Rails? 
Thanks

Comment: Unless you're a time traveller stuck twenty years in the past, you'd be better off using something like [Sinatra](http://www.sinatrarb.com/) for really simple web applications than some clunky CGI script. Then you can set the `action` attribute to your routed endpoint.

Comment: what if you already have a web server and don't want to change it?

Answer (score 0):

If you really need to use CGI, have a look at [this](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/ruby/ruby_web_applications.htm).

But if you don't absolutely need CGI, use [Sinatra](http://www.sinatrarb.com/), which is much more lightweight than Rails but much more comfortable than CGI.